# Clarification of Bondy's proof that an Ore graph on $n$ vertices has $\geq \frac{n^2}{4}$ edges

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

This question concerns a proof from [Bondy, Pancyclic Graphs 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895671900165) of the fact that a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices satisfying the condition that $d(u) + d(v) \geq n$ for any non-adjacent vertices $u,v$ has at  least $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges. The proof is:

> Let $k$ be the minimum vertex degree in $G$. We assume that $k < \frac{n}{2}$ (otherwise there is nothing to prove). If there are $m$ vertices of degree $k$, then by Ore's condition, all of these vertices must be joined to one another. Hence $m 
> \leq k + 1$, and $m \neq k+1$ since G is Hamiltonian (and therefore connected). There are at least $n-k-1$ vertices of degree at least $n-k$ in G, namely those vertices that are not joined to one specific vertex of degree $k$.

After this, the lower bound follows. I don't follow the last part, namely that there are at least $n-k-1$ vertices of degree $n-k$ in $G$. I understand that if a vertex $v$ is not adjacent to *all* vertices of degree $k$ (i.e. there is a vertex of degree $k$ not adjacent to $v$) then $d(v) \geq n-k$ by the Ore condition.

But where does the $n-k-1$ estimate come from? I suppose it's a lower bound for $n-m - 1$ (since $m \leq k$) but if that's the case I don't see why there should be *at most* one vertex of degree $>k$ connected to all vertices of degree $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\deg(v) = k < \frac n2$, then out of the $n$ vertices in the graph, you have:

1. One vertex which is $v$;
2. $k$ vertices which are neighbors of $v$;
3. $n-k-1$ vertices which are not neighbors of $v$.

If a vertex $w$ is in the third category, then Ore's condition says $\deg(v) + \deg(w) \ge n$, hence $\deg(w) \ge n-k$. So all vertices in the third category have degree at least $n-k$.

---

That answers your question, but let me also try to say a bit about what the proof is doing and why.

The proof leads with the $m \ne k+1$ reasoning because that's where it logically should go, but it's educational to see what happens if we try to continue *without* doing it.

Then we can see from the above that we have $k+1$ vertices of degree at least $k$, and $n-k-1$ vertices of degree at least $n-k$. The number of edges is half the sum of the degrees, so it is at least $$\frac12k(k+1) + \frac12(n-k)(n-k-1).$$ We can rewrite this as $(k - \frac{n-1}{2})^2 + \frac{n^2-1}{4}$, which is at least $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ because $(k - \frac{n-1}{2})^2 \ge 0$.

We want to get at least $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges and we are nearly there! The only way that we can end up below this number is if $k = \frac{n-1}{2}$ (so that $(k - \frac{n-1}{2})^2=0$) and if all of our inequalities up until this point are tight: all vertices in the second category have degree exactly $k$, and all vertices in the third category have degree exactly $n-k$. If this were possible, we'd only have $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ edges.

This is where the reasoning the proof leads with comes in. If all vertices in the second category have degree $k$, then you have $k+1$ vertices of degree $k = \frac{n-1}{2}$; then all of them must be adjacent, because otherwise we'd violate Ore's condition. That *already* gives $k$ neighbors to each of those $k+1$ vertices, so they must not have any additional neighbors: they form a $(k+1)$-vertex clique. This is a problem for two reasons:

- As the proof says, this makes the graph disconnected, which violates Ore's theorem that it must actually be Hamiltonian.
- Alternatively, we reason that the other $n-k-1 = \frac{n-1}{2}$ vertices can have degree at most $\frac{n-3}{2}$, because they can only be adjacent to each other; but they were supposed to have degree $n-k = \frac{n+1}{2}$, instead.

So this exceptional situation with only $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ edges is impossible, and therefore we always have at least $\frac{n^2}{4}$.

Comment: Wow, it was pretty obvious, wasn't it? Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, the proof is much clearer now! (+1)